# How do I pull the values from multiple columns, conditionally, into a new column?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, recode

I am a relatively novice R user, though familiar with dplyr and tidy verse. I still can't seem to figure out how to pull in the actual data from one column if it meets certain condition, into a new column.

Here is what I'm trying to do. Participants have ranked specific practices (n=5) and provided responses to questions that represent their beliefs about these practices. I want to have five new columns that assign their beliefs about the practices to their ranks, rather than the practices.

For example, they have a score for "beliefs about NI" called ni.beliefs, if a participant ranked NI as their first choice, I want the value for ni.beliefs to be pulled into the new column for first.beliefs. The same is true that if a participant put pmii as their first choice practice, their value for pmii.beliefs should be pulled into the first.beliefs column.

So, I need five new columns called: first.beliefs, second.beliefs, third.beliefs, fourth.beliefs, last.beliefs and then I need each of these to have the data pulled in conditionally from the practice specific beliefs (ni.beliefs, dtt.beliefs, pmi.beliefs, sn.beliefs, script.beliefs) dependent on the practice specific ranks (rank assigned of 1-5 for each practice, rank.ni, rank.dtt, rank.pmi, rank.sn, rank.script).

Here is what I have so far but I am stuck and aware that this is not very close. Any help is appreciated!!!

`

```
Diss$first.beliefs <-ifelse(rank.ni==1, ni.beliefs,
                    ifelse(rank.dtt==1, dtt.beliefs,
                           ifelse(rank.pmi==1, pmi.beliefs,
                                  ifelse(rank.sn, sn.beliefs,
                                         ifelse(rank.script==1, script.beliefs)))))
```

`

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have some sample data?

Comment: @mariah It is policy when asking questions on S.O. to make them "Reproducible". People do not have your data but (for example) can you use the iris data(?) to show your point and allow others to reproduce your idea(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done very easily with the case_when() function. You can improve on the code below.

```
library(dplyr)

Diss$first.beliefs <- case_when(
  rank.ni == 1 ~ ni.beliefs,
  rank.dtt == 1 ~ dtt.beliefs,
  rank.pmi == 1 ~ pmi.beliefs,
  rank.sn ~ sn.beliefs,
  rank.script == 1 ~ script.beliefs
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had been considering applying case_when but didn't know how it pulled valued from other columns. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you if you could upvote my answer so I can continue to improve my reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly (it would help if you show how your data looks like), but this is what I'm thinking:

Without using additional packages, if the ranking columns are equivalent to the index of the new columns you want (i.e. they rank each practice from 1 to 5, without repeats, and in the same order as the new columns "firsts belief, second belief, etc"), then you can use that data as the indices for the second set of columns:

```
for(j in 1:nrow(people_table)){
people_table[j,]$first.belief[[1]] <- names(beliefs)[(people_table[j,c(A:B)]) %in% 1]
people_table[j,]$second.belief[[1]] <- names(beliefs)[(people_table[j,c(A:B)]) %in% 2]
...
}
```

Where

```
A -> index of the first preference rank column

B -> index of the last preference rank column

(people_table[j,c(A:B)] %in% 1) -> this returns something like (FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE)

beliefs -> vector with the names of each belief
```

That should work. It's simple, no need for packages, and it'll be fast too. Just make sure you've initialized/created the new columns first, otherwise you'll get some errors. If

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian! The code above from user2332849 worked, so I ended up not needing this but I think your logic and code make sense!